# Azure Web App sometimes slow to respond

Tags: azure

I have inherited a basic Azure Web App as part of a system that needs to be very responsive. The system sends an HTTP POST to my Azure server which then processes the message and sends a response. Most of the time the server responds in about 0.4s which is fine however there are occasions when the response time jumps to several seconds.

I have instrumented the code and captured the time from when the POST is sent from my system to when the App first get kicked off by the POST arriving and the delay seems to be from the POST being sent to the App starting (not in the App itself). This is all in the working of Azure and I do not know of any way of getting any further metrics.

My Web App is always on with auto scaling I do not see any obvious problems on the Azure console. My tests send a POST every few seconds so I would not expect the App to go to sleep.

Comment: I would start with logging all app_start events to understand if you have delay because of web app restart (for whatever reason), of with something else

Comment: also, try using AlwaysOn and see if it solves the issue for you

Comment: I can confirm the App is Always On
Having done some further measurements I can confirm that there are 2 causes for the delay. The first is down to slow SQL database access. This is typically less that 0.5s but can jump to over 5s. The second, more puzzling, delay is from my POST to the App starting. I have looked at the event logs and there is nothing that stands out as unusual.